# Moonbeam Unified Accounts Implementation

Tags: frontier, moonbeam

Moonbeam implemented unified accounts to use H160 address type across all network is quit old, is there any codebase available to implement same with newly generated frontier node template or is it already implemented into the frontier codebase? because there's no documentation available for that and the docs for frontier not being updated for quit long. Any guide that I can follow without swimming through all the commit history of moonbeam to figure out the implementation will be a great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this PR can help you to figure out the changes you need to implement the moonbeam unified account H160.
https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/pull/78

Doc reference: https://docs.moonbeam.network/learn/features/unified-accounts/

for more information maybe you can join the moonbeam discord server can discuss with developers.